# JNA invalid memory access

Tags: java, c++, jna

I'm testing JNA before wrapping big dll. Basic functions with different types args works. But when we wrap (even simple) approved code which has standard method [**mbstowcs_s**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/eyktyxsx(v=vs.100).aspx) inside, appears:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
    at com.sun.jna.Native.invokePointer(Native Method)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invokePointer(Function.java:490)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invokeString(Function.java:654)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:427)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:354)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:244)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.TestWCHAR_in(Unknown Source)
    at gov.nbu.App.main(App.java:85)
```

All versions 32bit.

Comment: Don't send a `String` (`const char*`) where you should be sending a `WString` (`const wchar_t*`).  You can set things up so that `String` automatically defaults to `const wchar_t*` instead of `const char*`, but that's a different issue.

Comment: @technomage, error apears even in void methods without args.

Comment: Since you are calling a WinAPI function, have you remembered to extend from `StdCallLibrary` instead of `Library`?

Comment: @cubrr, yes. Result the same.

Comment: Could you show an example function in both Java and the native language which throws this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem wasn't in JNA. It appears on Cpp side on some machines (my case). Here it is:

```
void TestVoid(void)
{
    wchar_t                     wcBuffer[2600]      = {};
    size_t                      szOut               = 0;
    std::string                 Path                = "This message for test WCHAR.";
    errno_t                     errCode             = 0;

    // Work:
    errCode = mbstowcs_s(&szOut, wcBuffer, sizeof(wcBuffer), (char*)Path.c_str(), Path.size());
    // Not work:
    errCode = mbstowcs_s(&szOut, wcBuffer, Path.size(), (char*)Path.c_str(), Path.size()); 
}
```

Comment: How could under-reporting the size of your buffer result in "Invalid Memory Access"?